# While iterating over products using *ngFor, how do I transmit each product to the component?

Tags: angular

I am iterating over a products array as shown here:

```
<div  *ngFor="let product of products; setCurrentProduct(product)">
    <img class="img-fluid" 
       src="assets/img/category/{{currentProduct?.colors[0]?.images[0]}}">
</div>
```

I am trying to send each iterated product to the component using setCurrentProduct(product) as shown above but it is not working. I thought I had done this in the past.

Comment: I don't actually understand what you are trying to do because you already have products in component. Why you call setCurrentProduct? and actually you can not do that like this. there is no execution. The execution can be bound to an event (ex. click ). Can you please elaborate on what you need  to do ? so I can help you with this one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Directive

```
    @Directive({
      selector: '[refresh]'
    })
    export class RefreshDirective implements OnInit {
      @Output('refresh') init = new EventEmitter();
      ngOnInit() {
         this.init.emit()
      }
    }
```

2. Import the directive in the same module as the component with the above template
3. Update your Template;

```
    <div  *ngFor="let product of products" (refresh)="setCurrentProduct(product)">
        <img class="img-fluid" 
           src="assets/img/category/{{currentProduct?.colors[0]?.images[0]}}">
    </div>
```